# Some space mysteriously disapears on XFS filesystems

Tags: linux, debian, xfs

I have 2 XFS filesystems where space seems to disappear mysteriously.

The system (Debian) was installed many years ago (12 years ago, I think). The 2 XFS filesystems were created at that time. Since then, the system has been updated, both software and hardware, and both filesystems have been grown a few times. It’s now running 32-bit up-to-date Debian Jessie, with a 64-bit 4.9.2-2~bpo8+1 linux kernel from the backports archive.

Now, within days, I see that the used space on those filesystems grows, much more than it should because of the files. I have checked with `lsof +L1` that it’s not related to files that would have been deleted but kept open by some processes. I can reclaim the lost space by unmounting the filesystems and running `xfs_repair`.

Here is a transcript that shows it:

```
~# df -h /home
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-home  2.0G  1.7G  361M  83% /home
~# du -hsx /home
1.5G    /home
~# xfs_estimate /home
/home will take about 1491.8 megabytes
~# umount /home
~# xfs_repair /dev/system/home 
Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
Phase 2 - using internal log
        - zero log...
        - scan filesystem freespace and inode maps...
sb_fdblocks 92272, counted 141424
        - found root inode chunk
Phase 3 - for each AG...
        - scan and clear agi unlinked lists...
        - process known inodes and perform inode discovery...
        - agno = 0
        - agno = 1
        - agno = 2
        - agno = 3
        - agno = 4
        - agno = 5
        - agno = 6
        - agno = 7
        - process newly discovered inodes...
Phase 4 - check for duplicate blocks...
        - setting up duplicate extent list...
        - check for inodes claiming duplicate blocks...
        - agno = 0
        - agno = 2
        - agno = 1
        - agno = 3
        - agno = 4
        - agno = 5
        - agno = 6
        - agno = 7
Phase 5 - rebuild AG headers and trees...
        - reset superblock...
Phase 6 - check inode connectivity...
        - resetting contents of realtime bitmap and summary inodes
        - traversing filesystem ...
        - traversal finished ...
        - moving disconnected inodes to lost+found ...
Phase 7 - verify and correct link counts...
done

~# mount /home
~# df -h /home
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-home  2.0G  1.5G  521M  75% /home
~#
```

On this example, there were “only” 161MB that were lost, but if I wait too long, the filesystem is 100% full, and I have real problems…

If that matters, both filesystems are bind-mounted in a LXC container. (I don’t have any other XFS filesystem on this system.)

Does anybody has an idea why this happens or how I should investigate?

Comment: No need to tell me I should use a different filesystem. I already consider converting those to ext4. But after using XFS for more than 10 years with no problem, I’d still like to understand what’s happening.

Comment: Check out http://serverfault.com/questions/406069/why-are-my-xfs-filesystems-suddenly-consuming-more-space-and-full-of-sparse-file.

Comment: @FerencWágner Thanks for pointing this, it was very interesting. Unfortunately, I just tried defragmenting with `xfs_fsr -v`, flushing with `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, or mounting the filesystem with option `allocsize=4096`. None of them could reclaim the lost space. On the other hand, `xfs_repair` could. So my problem may be unrelated to the “XFS Dynamic Speculative EOF Preallocation”.

Comment: I have the same problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/865141/xfs-root-partition-free-space-inconsistency

It will be interesting to see if this kernel patch fixes the issue
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9566285/

Comment: In my case, `xfs_fsr -v` just solved my problem. But I don't know the exact cause.

Answer (score -1):

```
xfs_admin -c 1 xxx
```

use lazy-counters mode XFS.

Comment: Welcome to the site. OP asked what they were doing wrong. A good answer should address the question asked, not just provide an unexplained solution.